# How to use mixpanel in wix with some kind of event

Tags: events, properties, tracking, mixpanel, velo

I am not able to activate the track of the mixpanel in an onclik event. I tried to create the onclick event in wix, but in the page code it does not recognize the track command. Can someone help me? Sorry for my English.

I tried this in the button event on the WIX page

```
export function button10_click(event) {
mixpanel.track("TestEvent")}
```

mixpanel is not defined.

I want to track who enters the page and then get the property (email, name ...)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are seeing `mixpanel is not defined` leads me to believe that the mixpanel javascript library isn't being initialized on the webpage.

Are you installing Mixpanel on the page using the snippet? [This page describes how to install the library](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000865566-Set-up-Your-Tracking#install-the-mixpanel-library). You simply need to copy and paste the snippet and put it in the `<head>` tags, and make sure that you replace the token with your project token, as described.

I also see that you are looking to include properties with your event. The same article describes the syntax and [how to do that here](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000865566-Set-up-Your-Tracking#tracking-events).

I don't know much about Wix, but you might be able to place the snippet in the meta location [as described here](https://support.wix.com/en/article/adding-custom-meta-tags-to-your-site).

Good luck!